# VB.net Index Out Of Range Exception

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, indexing

This program loads a .txt splits it by ":" then takes each and checks them somewhere
I Have an error whenever my program reaches the end of the list Here is my code

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    If ListBox1.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Checking DONE")
    ElseIf ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString > 0 Then

        Dim str As String
        Dim strArr() As String

        str = ListBox1.Items(0)
        strArr = str.Split(":")
        If str.Count > 0 Then
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("email").SetAttribute("value", (strArr(0)))
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").SetAttribute("value", (strArr(1)))
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login-form-contBtn").InvokeMember("click")
            WaitForPageLoad()
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            Me.Button2.PerformClick()
        Else
            MsgBox("Done")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also the `Me.Button2.PerformClick()` clicks the button programmatically and then button two clicks this button and it should continue until the Listbox is empty but it just crashes/ gives [the error](http://gyazo.com/cb7c47bca69af101871035bf18231b6e)

This is the button that imports the list to the listbox

```
OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "./"
OpenFileDialog1.FileName = "Open a text file..."
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) | *.txt"
OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()

Dim R As New IO.StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
Dim string1 As String() = R.ReadToEnd().Split(New String(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))

ListBox1.Items.AddRange(string1)
R.Close()
ListBox1.SelectedItem = ListBox1.Items(0)

Dim str As String
Dim strArr() As String

str = ListBox1.SelectedItem
strArr = str.Split(":") 'Delimits the imported combo list
Label4.Text = (strArr(0)) 'Email
Label3.Text = (strArr(1)) 'Password
Label6.Text = (ListBox1.Items.Count) 'How big is combo?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You split `str` in strArr but you check for `str.Count`

```
str = ListBox1.Items(0)
strArr = str.Split(":")
If strArr.Count > 0 Then
   ....
```

The following code uses the index 0  and index 1 of the strArr so better to check for

```
If strArr.Count > 1 Then
```

Comment: Thank you!!! lol , Why is it index 1 instead of 0? , Just want to increase my knowledge

Comment: Every array in NET start at index 0. When you split the string in the strArr Count represents the number of elements present in the array, so a string XXXXX:YYYYY when splitted at : becomes a two elements array strArr(0)=XXXX, strArr(1)=YYYYY. If there is no : (XXXXXYYYYY) you still get an array from the split but  it is a one element array (strArr(0)=XXXXYYYYY). If you try to use index=1 on this array you get an exception because there is no element at index 1

Comment: Still don't understand that well, But thank you for helping out :)